# SAS Update database by month

Tags: sas

I have a bunch of database which is named by month (e.g. DB202301, DB202302 etc.) Every week, I am receiving a weekly DB (there is a column of image date) and I would like to append the weekly DB to the monthly DB automatically.

However, I have 2 problems:
1.difficulties during the last week of the month, when a few days belongs to the previous month and a few days belongs to the next month. Currently I'm manually separating the weekly DB to two datasets, and manually append it to the monthly DB. But I have to change the file name manually every month (e.g. append to DB202301 > append to DB202302) and I would like to make it automate

2. When the new month DB does not exist, how can I automatically create a new DB (e.g. create DB202306 when June 1st week data is coming) and export the data to the new monthly DB?

Comment: You are working in SAS, right? So what do you mean a "database"? Is it a single dataset with data? Or a library of several datasets?

Comment: Sorry maybe my wordings are not clear. I'm having several datasets named by month, and i will have a new dataset every week which need to be appended to the monthly datasets by the image date.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

Assuming you have some test data:

```
/* already existing data from previous months */
data DB202301 DB202302 DB202303;
  set sashelp.cars;
run;

/* data from March and Appril */
data newData;
  set sashelp.cars(obs=10);
  if _N_=1 then Date_variable='27mar2023'd;
           else Date_variable + 1;
  format Date_variable yymmdd10.;
run;
```

The following macro:

1. splits new data
2. make a (temporary) backup of old period data (just in case)
3. appends data to previous period data (March)
4. creates dataset for new period

```
%macro addData(newPeriod,newData);

/* split data between periods */
data old new;
  set &newData.;
  if Date_variable < input("&newPeriod.01",yymmdd10.) 
    then output OLD;
    else output NEW;
run;

%let oldPeriod=%sysfunc(sum(%sysfunc(inputn(&newPeriod.01,yymmdd10.)),-1),yymmN6.);
%put &=oldPeriod.;

/* backup in case error while update of old existing data */
data _temporary_backup_;
set DB&oldPeriod.;
run;

/* this will append to existing old period data set */
proc append BASE=DB&oldPeriod. NEW=old(drop=Date_variable);
run;

/* this will create new data set */
proc append BASE=DB&newPeriod. NEW=new(drop=Date_variable);
run;

%mend;

%addData(202304,work.newData)
```